# Could not execute menu item(internal Item) [exception] Could not perform service action:the service has not been started

Tags: server, wamp

I got this message when i am trying to Wampserver put online :
Could not execute menu item(internal Item) [exception] Could not perform service action:the service has not been started

Tell me the solution 
Thanks,
Purushottam

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. If you are not helping the question to get solved put a comment on the post instead. Or if you (as you want in this case) want to know how the question will get answered, mark it with a Star so you can follow the process instead.

Comment: You get this message if Apache is not running when you use the `Put Online` menu. What colour is your `wampmanager` icon?

Comment: Also, you do understand that you dont have to `Put Online` to run WAMPServer quite normally dont you. `Put Online` just changes the Apache `httpd.conf` file to allow access from the universe. **Thats probably not what you actually want to do**